# dl libs and pthreads required in GitHub Actions

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, github-actions

I'm developing a dynamic C++17 library that uses SQLite. It's a CMake project and the requirement for it to be dynamic comes because I plan to mainly use the library through JNI.

So, in my project I build SQLite as a static library:

```
add_library(sqlite3 STATIC "${sqlite3_SOURCE_DIR}/sqlite3.c") # STATIC to efficiently link to SHARED main library
set_target_properties(sqlite3 PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON) # Required to link STATIC to SHARED
target_include_directories(sqlite3 PUBLIC "${sqlite3_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

And my main library as shared:

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED <library sources>)
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}) # To include headers without using relative paths
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE sqlite3)
```

Then if I link my library to some executable like this it builds and runs absolutely fine on my PC:

```
add_executable(app <app's sources>)
target_compile_features(app PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_include_directories(app PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} <main library src dir>) # Including the main library like this is a temporary solution, because there is no separate include dir yet
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

But when I try to build it in GitHub Actions I get these errors:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable app
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/mylib.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/mylib.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/mylib.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/mylib.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/mylib.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/mylib.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/mylib.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/mylib.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/mylib.so: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/mylib.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can fix it by linking the library target to `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}` and `Threads::Threads`, but I'm not sure if I'm doing what should be done and not just silencing some other mistakes of mine.

To be clear, I don't use any of the functions mentioned in the errors above in the code of my library.

**The questions are:**

1. Why does the original code work on my PC and doesn't on GitHub Actions?
2. Is what I did the right way to fix this?

I'm building the project locally on Ubuntu 22.04 (WSL) with a compiler identified as `GNU 11.3.0`, while GitHub Actions runs Ubuntu 20.04 using `GNU 9.4.0` compiler.

Comment: "To be clear, I don't use any of the functions mentioned in the errors above in the code of my library." - Probably, these functions are used in `sqlite3` library. In that case, linkage with `CMAKE_DL_LIBS` should be performed in the project which creates `sqlite3`. Ultimately, if a code of a target directly uses a function from some library, then given target should be linked with that library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I thought about this and indeed `sqlite3` uses both `pthreads.h` and `dlfcn.h` (a dl library). Then I should link these libraries to the sqlite3 target. But still, why does the project builds locally without mentioning these libraries?

Comment: "why does the project builds locally without mentioning these libraries?" - We could only **speculate** about the reason why your project successfully built. It could be that your project has some conditionals which differs on host and on the GitHub Actions. Actually, the error message is quite.. unusual for a CMake build. The problem is with your `mylib` library, so you should get an error when **build** the library, not when you **use** it for the `app` executable. Smells like your project modifies linker flags responsible for detection of such errors. It is better to not do that.